# How do I align my expanded row data with main table's column in material UI's collapsible table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've got a functionality in which, when the user clicks on expand icon Row will be expanded. I want to align that expanded Rows data with the column of the Main table, I'm using material UI's collapsible table component for carrying out this operation!

**How to implement this functionality in HTML/CSS?**

I've created an example, to describe the issue more clearly!
Here's the link to the codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-allen-im8tj9?file=/src/App.js

As you can see nested row (expanded row) fields are not aligning with its parent columns! How do I align them properly with its parent columns?

i want to do something like this

[image]

Any suggestions / help will be appreciated, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by passing a ref to the main table's TableHead's first TableRow (the one that usually has column names), passing that as a prop in the expanded row's Table, and using `colgroup` along with `getBoundingClientRect().width` from the ref's children. I wanted a responsive table and doing this would dynamically change the column widths of the expanded rows table, based on the main table's columns. Here's a sample, potentially_unoptimized_since_I_just_got_it_working, code

```
export const MainTableComp = () => {
  ...
  const ref = useRef(null);
  ...
  return <TableContainer>
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow ref={ref}>
          <TableCell>Order Ids</TableCell>
          ...
            <ExpandedRow mainTableEl={ref}>
            ...
};

export const ExpandedRow = ({ mainTableEl }) => {
  ...
  const [colWidths, setColWidths] = useState<Array<number>>([]);
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    setColWidths(
      Array.from(tableEl.current?.children || []).map(c => {
        return c.getBoundingClientRect().width
      })
    )
  }, [tableEl.current?.children[0].getBoundingClientRect()]); // if one column's width changes, the rest's, and 0's, would be too

  return <Fragment>
    ...
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <Table>
          <colgroup>
            {
              colWidths.map((cW, idx) => {
                return <col key={idx} style={{ width: cW }}></col>
              })
            }
          </colgroup>
          ...

};
```

Comment: You have to remove "tableEl.current?.children[0].getBoundingClientRect()]" from dependency array cause using this like that will end in an infinite loop. Try pass just the ref (tableEl) as dependency. Here works good :D

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. The only way to fix this was to create an 'invisible' header for the subitems and dynamically set the width of the columns. For me, the working code looks like this:

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (openedItem) {
    const hardcodeWidths = () => {
      const headers = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('headerCell'));
      const subTableParentRow = document.getElementsByClassName(`expandable_${openedItem}`)[0]
      const subTableColumns = subTableParentRow.getElementsByClassName('subTableColumn');
      headers.forEach((header, i) => {
        (subTableColumns[i] as HTMLElement).style.width = `${header.clientWidth}px`
      })
    }
    
    hardcodeWidths()
    addEventListener('resize', hardcodeWidths)
    return () => {
      removeEventListener('resize', hardcodeWidths)
    }
  }
}, [openedItem])
```

```html
<Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="Talaria table" >
  <TableHead className={style.tableHead}>
    <TableRow>
      {props.hasStickyFirstRow && <TableCell />}
      {props.headers.cells.map((cell, index) => (
        <TableCell className='headerCell' align="center" key={index}>{cell.displayValue}</TableCell>  
      ))}
      {props.hasStickyFirstRow && <TableCell />}
    </TableRow>

    {props.hasStickyFirstRow &&
      <TableRow className={style.stickyHeader}>
        <TableCell> <LockedProtected className={style.tableLockIcon}/> </TableCell>
        {props.headers.cells.map((cell, index) => (
          <TableCell align="center" key={index}>
            {props.selectedStickyRow[cell.key]}
          </TableCell>
        ))}
        <TableCell/>
      </TableRow>
    }
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
    {(rowsPerPage > 0
      ? props.rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
      : props.rows
    ).map((row) => {
      return(
        <>
          <TableRow
            key={row[props.uniqueElement]}
            sx={{
              '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 },
              ...(!(props.hasStickyFirstRow) && {
              cursor: 'pointer',
              }),
            }}
            className={style.tableBody}
            onClick={props.canClickRow ? () => props.onRowClick(row) : undefined}
          >
            { props.hasStickyFirstRow && <TableCell>
              <IconButton
                aria-label="expand row"
                size="small"
                onClick={() => setOpenedItem(openedItem === row[props.uniqueElement] ? '' : row[props.uniqueElement] )}
              >
                {openedItem === row[props.uniqueElement] ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
              </IconButton>
            </TableCell>}
            {props.headers.cells.map((cell) => (
              <TableCell align="center">
                {row[cell.key]}
              </TableCell>
            ))}
            { props.hasStickyFirstRow && <TableCell>
              <Radio
                checked={row[props.uniqueElement] === props.selectedRadioRowId}
                onChange={() => props.setSelectedRadioRowId && props.setSelectedRadioRowId(row[props.uniqueElement])}
                // TODO: disabled  // Here will need to add a logic to be disabled or maybe  primary color or 'secondary' if the table is disabled
              />
            </TableCell>}
          </TableRow>
          { props.hasStickyFirstRow && <TableRow className={`expandable_${row[props.uniqueElement]}`}>
            {/* TODO: when BE comes with a data format please make sure to change the keys (also up) */}
            {/* Added this table cell for alignment purposes */}
            <TableCell key={'dummyStartCell'} style={{padding: 0}}/> 
            <TableCell style={{ padding: 0 }} colSpan={props.headers.cells.length}>
              <Collapse in={openedItem === row[props.uniqueElement]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <Table >
                  <colgroup>
                    {props.headers.cells.map(() => (
                      <col className='subTableColumn' />
                    ))}
                  </colgroup>
                  <TableBody>
                    {row.rowDetails.map((rowDetails:any, key:string) => (
                      <TableRow key={key} className='subtableCell' sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }} >
                        {props.headers.cells.map((cell, index) => (
                          <TableCell align="center" key={cell.key}>
                            {rowDetails[cell.key]}
                          </TableCell>
                        ))}
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                  </TableBody>
                </Table>
              </Collapse>
            </TableCell>
            {/* Added this table cell for alignment purposes */}
            <TableCell key={'dummyEndCell'} style={{padding: 0}}/> 
        </TableRow> }
      </>
    )})}
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```